# How to install the qiskit packages and libraries?

Tags: qiskit

We are doing a Quantum computing project using the Qiskit toolkit. But we are struggling to import or install the packages and libraries. In Qiskit how we can import the libraries and packages?

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77889759/8508004) for this already being posted and answered.

Answer (score 2):

### Environment Setup Guide for Qiskit

Either you can make a virtual environment and install everything in there, it's optional but recommended or you can directly install qiskit. It depends on where you are installing it.

#### 1. Open the terminal or command prompt and type

```py
pip install qiskit
```

or

```py
pip3 install qiskit
```

and if you have jupyter notebook installed in your device, you can make use of

```py
%pip install qiskit
```

#### 2. Installing other dependencies

Some packages that are required with `qiskit` are not directly installed with this, you need to install them separately.

**Qiskit Visualization**

```py
%pip install qiskit[visualization]
```

**Qiskit Machine Learning**

```py
%pip install qiskit[machine-learning]
```

#### 3. Checking installation

If you want to know which version of qiskit package is installed, and which isn't. You can make use of following

```py
import qiskit
qiskit.__qiskit_version__
```

or you can check them in a table

```py
import qiskit.tools.jupyter
%qiskit_version_table
```

---

Having `pip` installed will ease up a lot of things for you, since then you only have to type

```py
pip install <your package name>
```

and it will be installed.

Make sure that if you are writing in terminal it will be `pip` and if installing in Jupyter it will be  `%pip`.

#### 4. Importing

Importing them is also easy, all you have to do is:

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_vector
```

---

Meanwhile, you can also take a look at the official `Qiskit` page on how to install it:

[Install and Set up](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/start/install)