# Installation Struggle

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, quantum-computing, qiskit

We are doing a Quantum computing project using the Qiskit toolkit. But we are struggling to import or install the packages and libraries. In Qiskit how we can import the libraries and packages?

Clarify the doubt for how to install the libraries from outsources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation Struggles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885801/installation-struggles) <==== [That shows this was already posted on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885801/installation-struggles) and should not have been reposted. Please research always before posting. Search and researching your issue is the second sub-heading in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which you should read and follow as a guide to posting here.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to start working with Qiskit would be to follow the official [Qiskit documentation](https://www.ibm.com/quantum/qiskit). For the installation process you can follow [this link](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/start/install), but in general, the easiest way to start would be to run the following series of commands in terminal, assuming you are working with MacOS (for Windows, check out the link above)

1. Create a directory with you project name (i.e., `my_project`)
2. Open a terminal window and `cd` into the it using

```
cd <enter-here-the-path-to-my_project>
```

3. Create a Python 3 virtual environment using

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

4. Activate the Python virtual environment by running

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

5. Once activated, you can check out the packages you have installed on that environment by running

```
pip list
```

since you haven't installed any packages yet, you should see only the default ones, which are (maybe in different versions)

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.5.0
```

6. Then, in order to install Qiskit in the current activated environment, run

```
pip install qiskit
```

The installation should take about a minute, but once done you can check that qiskit is installed by running in the same terminal

```
python
```

then, in the Python environment (you will see `>>>` appearing)

```
>>> import qiskit
>>> qiskit.__version__
```

if installed, you should get the version printed, then type

```
>>> exit()
```

Now, if you would like to work with a Jupyter Notebook, just install it via `pip` by following the [Jupyter installation](https://jupyter.org/install). Finally, once you have Qiskit and Jupyter Notebook installed, you can follow the Qiskit's official [hello-world tutorial](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/start/hello-world).