# Cannot import qiskit to VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, quantum-computing, qiskit

I have a problem of importing qiskit in visual studio code.

I have already installed the extension package 'qiskit-vscode' v0.5.5 provided by VS Code, but there is still an error of importing the qiskit. Please let me know what makes it wrong. Is there any alternative way to run quantum 'qiskit' code on VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you have installed the vscode extension but you haven't actually created a Python environment and installed the Qiskit package in that environment using `pip install qiskit`.
If that is the case, you should check out the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889759/installation-struggle/77894398#77894398).